# how to take panorama image in swift, iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

simple and straight question is,

how to take panorama images and show them in imageView in swift 4 or 5,

image will be shown in scrollView i know, but how to take panorama image from camera, pleas any one help me that..

Comment: Have you checked [CTPanoramaView](https://github.com/scihant/CTPanoramaView) library yet?

Comment: this library, takes an image from that is in project, but i want to take a new image from camera as panorama...

Comment: Consider posting what you have already tried, links you have seen and tried to use. Asking how to do something without providing any information to the community on what you have tried and failed with and so on..